# scaling svg figure

Tags: svg, librsvg, rsvg

I tried to resize svg file to be opened in illustrator with smaller width and height(pixels or cm), I did this by changing width, height and viewBox attributes in `<svg>` tag, but it doesn't work at all. By search I have found that transform attribute via matrix value affects the real resizing of the figure, any ideas about ready made functions or scripts using python or librsvg to successfully scaling the svg figure, by the way I'm using inkscape to produce svg files. THANKS

Answer (score 1):

You could try [svg scour](http://www.codedread.com/scour/), that should be able to find a good viewBox to use (note spellning and uppercase 'B'). Then change only the width and height attributes to be whatever you want, and hopefully that should work.

Comment: Amazing answer. Running scour --renderer-workaround solved a very perplexing rsvg issue I was having.